# How to programmatically change label and font size

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, resize, label

I am building an RPN calculator in xCode v6.1.1, and am trying to modify the x register label size and font size, and be able to toggle between the x register label and the four x-y-z-t label registers.  I've tried this code and it works with one line but not both.

I've found that with both lines in the method, if I press the toggle button twice, the function will work.

```
self.xReg.frame = CGRectMake(188, 206, 385, 70);
[self.xReg setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:70]];
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code? It seems that your problem lies outside of these 2 lines.

Comment: To pile onto @PassKit: we appreciate the effort to post only the relevant code, but what you should be striving for is a minimum, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're missing the "complete" and "verifiable" attributes.